# Is there anything i can do to recover the data?

Tags: hard-drive

[image]I am running ubuntu 22.04.1. Whenever I try to copy the files over i get the error "Error while copying "file name here" There was an error copying the file into Home/downloads
Error splicing file input/output error
the files seem to play back fine. Video files
In disks it says partition okay with 45 bad sectors
is there anything i can do?

The drive is a sata hard drive and i am trying to copy it over to the system drive which is a nvme ssd

Comment: Is is Downloads with a capital d. Linux is case-sensitive. And in case you typed it yourse;f: please edit the question to include the actual command and message ;-)

Comment: I have added an image.

Comment: There is no version called current of Ubuntu. You need an actual version number. What if someone if reading this in the future? There are always at least 2 version that could be called current.

Comment: What kind of device are you copying from? Is it a USB disk formatted in some non-native format?

Comment: I have added the Ubuntu version and drive type to the post

Comment: I used to see this  "splicing file error" when I used USB data drives that weren't ext4 formatted to copy big files, but it was a long time ago.

Answer (score 1):

From the details in your post, it sounds like your drive is damaged and nearing failure.

> Error splicing file input/output error

Input/output errors are basically what happens when the system tells a drive to read or write some data, and the drive tells the system "Yeah I ain't doin' that." It is a usually irreparable problem when it results from trying to read data from the drive. Once the drive starts throwing out I/O errors when trying to read some data, it's over. Whatever bit of data was on the sector in question, is now gone. [1]

> Video files In disks it says partition okay with 45 bad sectors is there anything i can do?

If this is the drive that you are trying to copy from, then yes and no. As you have already discovered, just trying to copy the files will probably fail. You may be able to use a tool like `ddrescue` to recover the files that can't be copied, though. (You can install it with `sudo apt install gddrescue`, the "g" is important.) `ddrescue` can work around I/O errors, recovering as much data as possible from the drive and leaving the bad sectors behind. However, this solution comes with some disadvantages - you will still lose the data in the bad sectors, and depending on what's happening to the drive internally, the activity from copying the files may actually make the drive break further before it finishes recovering data. Still, if you must attempt data recovery yourself, this is probably the best solution.

If that sounds too risky, the other solution would be to take the damaged drive to a professional data recovery lab. They may be able to recover data even from the bad sectors, however they almost certainly will charge an extremely high fee for doing so, sometimes thousands of dollars. If the data on the drive just isn't that important, and you can't recover it yourself well enough, you may elect to just discard it.

Obviously, if you have backups of your data, then it's going to be way easier to just restore from backups. I assume you don't have backups, however.

In any event, once you have recovered/discarded/retrieved the data, the hard drive with the I/O errors should no longer be used for data storage. If it's eating your data now, there's no good reason to trust it with more of your data in the future.

Footnotes:

[1]: OK so technically the data *may* still be there, but to the drive, it's not accessible anymore. So unless you intend on taking the drive to a data recovery lab, the data can be treated as gone.